Does anyone know how to close a browser tab using seleniumbase?
I open a page, then from that page I open links in new tabs, perform actions and return to the original page:
driver.switch_to_window(i)
current_url = driver.get_current_url()
title_text = driver.get_text('h1[data-additional-zone="title"]')
time.sleep(random.uniform(16, 26))
driver.switch_to_default_window()

but the other tabs remain open. Nowhere in the documentation did I find information about closing. Who knows how to close the current tab?

Use an English title otherwise this will only get downvotes. The title is half the question. People open questions only if the title looks linteresting

As for closing the current window, there are a lot of duplicates. Use driver.close()

The seleniumbase driver has all the original Selenium driver methods, plus new ones. driver.close() will close the current tab (from original Selenium).
Here are the new driver methods added by SeleniumBase:
driver.open(url)  # Like driver.get(), but allows partial URLs without protocol
driver.click(selector)
driver.click_link(link_text)
driver.click_if_visible(selector)
driver.click_active_element()
driver.send_keys(selector, text)
driver.press_keys(selector, text)
driver.type(selector, text)
driver.submit(selector)
driver.assert_element(selector)
driver.assert_element_present(selector)
driver.assert_element_not_visible(selector)
driver.assert_text(text, selector)
driver.assert_exact_text(text, selector)
driver.wait_for_element(selector)
driver.wait_for_element_visible(selector)
driver.wait_for_element_present(selector)
driver.wait_for_selector(selector)
driver.wait_for_text(text, selector)
driver.wait_for_exact_text(text, selector)
driver.wait_for_and_accept_alert()
driver.wait_for_and_dismiss_alert()
driver.is_element_present(selector)
driver.is_element_visible(selector)
driver.is_text_visible(text, selector)
driver.is_exact_text_visible(text, selector)
driver.is_attribute_present(selector, attribute)
driver.get_text(selector)
driver.js_click(selector)
driver.get_active_element_css()
driver.get_locale_code()
driver.get_origin()
driver.get_user_agent()
driver.highlight(selector)
driver.highlight_click(selector)
driver.highlight_if_visible(selector)
driver.sleep(seconds)
driver.locator(selector)
driver.get_attribute(selector, attribute)
driver.get_page_source()
driver.get_title()
driver.switch_to_frame(frame)

